# Unit tests discovered, but not running in VS 2015

Tags: python, c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to use the Unit Test Manager feature of Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition, and it discovers the tests successfully; however, when trying to run the tests (either by using the "Run All" option, or by right-clicking and selecting "Run selected tests"), the test is never run; the green progress bar at the top scrolls across indefinitely.

Initially I thought it was a problem with the C++ unit testing suite specifically, but I have just tried it with the Python unit tests too, and I am encountering the same problem. Does anyone have any workarounds, or is this even a known issue with Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: I have the same problem with Python 2.7.10 x86 and Visual Studio 2015 Professional

Comment: I tried with Python too, and I have the same issue; so I think it must be the unit test framework.

Answer (score 1):

After applying [Visual Studio 2015 Update 1](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691129) and having [PTVS 2.2.2](https://az837309.vo.msecnd.net/download/PTVS%202.2.2%20VS%202015.msi) everything started working for me.